# Serializing of System.Windows.Ink.StrokeCollection

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, collections, stroke

I need to transmit throught the net complex object `System.Windows.Ink.StrokeCollection`. How can I serialize it? This type do not implements `ISerializable` interface. I am using `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter` for serializing.
I already thinking about XML serialization of open field of my strokes collection and transmiting this XML as common string, but it will create a greater load on the network and affect the overall performance.
Is there any way to serialize my collection to a byte array to transmit it?

Comment: Do you really need all the values of each StrokeCollection item? Can you not make a wrapper class and deserialize that object and create the stroke collection item on the other end?

Comment: I need lots of fields, your offer is extreme and undesirable solution.

Comment: "extreme and undesirable" hehe, that is something new.

Comment: Gave you the answer, I was just asking if you needed all of the fields in the beginning. But anyway, there's a way.

Comment: Leo Lorenzo Luis, agree, I just meant that I am trying to find more simple and elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The StrokeCollection has a **Save(Stream)** method which Saves the StrokeCollection to the specified Stream.

Here is a way of serializing **StrokeCollection**

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (memoryStream)
{
    StrokeCollection strokeCollection; //Your stroke collection ommitted the declaration
    strokeCollection.Save(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;
}
```

Now when you want to deserialize it back you can pass the MemoryStream to the constructor of the **StrokeCollection**.

More can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms522846). That's how I would do it.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I could not find nowhere else.